# Does not work get_context_data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-users

I use custom user model with two entities:

```
class WeddyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(
    'Юзернейм',
    max_length=50,
    unique=True,
    db_index=True
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
    'Электронная почта',
    max_length=255,
    blank=True,
    null=True
   )
    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(
    'Волшебник',
    default=False
   )
   #other atributes and methodes
```

This class is inherited by two other user types:

```
class Vendor(WeddyUser):
   org_name = models.CharField('Название организации', max_length=50, blank=True)
   slug = models.SlugField('Короткое название', unique=True)
   city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True)
   description = models.TextField('О себе', blank=True)
```

and

```
class PlainUser(WeddyUser):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField('Дата рождения', null=True, blank=True)
    favor_news = models.ManyToManyField('news.News',  blank=True)
    favor_pic = models.ManyToManyField('news.Photo', blank=True)
```

I try to build personal area for this types of user:

in urls:

```
url(r'^desktop/$', views.DesktopView.as_view(), name='desktop'),
```

in template:

```
"{% url 'desktop'  %}"
```

in view:

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(object):

@classmethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
    return login_required(view)


class DesktopView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = WeddyUser
    context_object_name = 'weddyuser'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DesktopView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.user.is_vendor:
        context['vendor']= Vendor.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
    context['plainuser']= PlainUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
    return context

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    user = request.user
    if user.is_vendor:
        return render_to_response('user/vendor_edit_profile.html', RequestContext(request, c))
    return render_to_response('user/user_edit_profile.html', RequestContext(request, c))
```

But, I can't get access to `'vendor'` or `'plainuser'` context objects, also `'weddyuser'` context also doesn't work. I suppose my get function renders template without any context objects

Comment: You are not getting the key in context data or you are getting the values as None?

Comment: I don't understand where the `user.is_vendor` property is supposed to come from.

Comment: I haveattribute `    is_vendor = models.BooleanField( default=False)`, sorry I did not specified it

Comment: I suppose that does't work ` get_context_data() `, because I added print('anything')  and didn't wath nothing in terminal

Comment: Did you set the AUTH_USER_MODEL in the settings? What is the type of request.user?

Comment: Yes. ` 'AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.WeddyUser'' `

Comment: Is this indentation the same as in your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this code,

```
context['vendor']= Vendor.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
context['plainuser']= PlainUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
```

to this,

```
context['vendor']= Vendor.objects.get(weddyuser_ptr_id=self.request.user.id)
context['plainuser']= PlainUser.objects.get(weddyuser_ptr_id=self.request.user.id)
```

Pass context data in return statement,

```
return render_to_response('user/vendor_edit_profile.html', self.get_context_data() ,RequestContext(request, c))
return render_to_response('user/user_edit_profile.html', self.get_context_data(), RequestContext(request, c))
```

Comment: sorry, for what? If I add `abstract = True` I get `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The model WeddyUser is abstract, so it cannot be registered with admin.`

Comment: I have editted the answer, please change the context['vendor'] and context['plainuser'] queryset.

Comment: I tried - nothing. As I said above, I think my get function doesn't pass any context object into template. Beacuse I can't use also context_object_name = 'weddyuser'

Comment: Don't make the WeddyUser Abstract, the way U did it, you will not have a duplicate ID between the Vendor and plain user table. If U do it as abstract, it is like defining two different tables with some common properties

Comment: I've added self.get_context_data() and got the next error `AttributeError at /accounts/desktop/  'DesktopView' object has no attribute 'object'`

Comment: Then I added `self.object = self.get_object()` and `self.get_context_data(object=self.object)` it works. But after I got `Generic detail view DesktopView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.`

Comment: It seems I found. I edited my url `url(r'^desktop/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DesktopView.as_view(), name='desktop'),` and it's ok. Now I need only compare requested pk and pk of user instance